# Can __Slots__ in python be used to improve performance overhead in a program with many objects?

Tags: python, class

Can **Slots** in python be used to improve performance overhead in a class heavy script, or does it mainly impact memory usage?

Comment: They often go hand in hand. Less memory usage = more stuff that can fit in the processor's cache. Profile and find out for sure.

Comment: It should indeed improve both, but it also depends on what _else_ you're doing. Profile your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: This will help you further! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots